# To get the Amount using Self Join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a `Last_Year_Net_Amount` from a given table as per the output shown below. I've tried a Left Self join. However, I am getting all my values as `NULL`. Can anyone please help me understand where am I going wrong? This is on SQL Server

```
SELECT A1.*, A2.Net_Amount AS LY_Net_Amount
FROM Account AS A1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account AS A2
    ON A1.Account_ID = A2.Account_ID
    AND A1.Location_ID = A2.Location_ID
    AND A1.LY_Fiscal_Period = A2.Fiscal_Period
```

Account:

```
Account_ID  Location_ID  Fiscal_Period  LY_Fiscal_Period  Net_Amount
A1          L1           2019001        2018001           180
A1          L1           2019002        2018002           200
A1          L1           2019003        2018003           220
A1          L1           2019010        2018010           240
A1          L1           2019011        2018011           260
A1          L1           2019012        2018012           280
A1          L1           2020001        2019001           300
A1          L1           2020002        2019002           320
A1          L1           2020003        2019003           340
```

Expected output:

```
Account_ID  Location_ID  Fiscal_Period  LY_Fiscal_Period  Net_Amount  LY_Net_Amount
A1          L1           2019001        2018001           180         NULL
A1          L1           2019002        2018002           200         NULL
A1          L1           2019003        2018003           220         NULL
A1          L1           2019010        2018010           240         NULL
A1          L1           2019011        2018011           260         NULL
A1          L1           2019012        2018012           280         NULL
A1          L1           2020001        2019001           300         180
A1          L1           2020002        2019002           320         200
A1          L1           2020003        2019003           340         220
```

The output I am getting:

```
Account_ID  Location_ID  Fiscal_Period  LY_Fiscal_Period  Net_Amount  LY_Net_Amount
A1          L1           2019001        2018001           180         NULL
A1          L1           2019002        2018002           200         NULL
A1          L1           2019003        2018003           220         NULL
A1          L1           2019010        2018010           240         NULL
A1          L1           2019011        2018011           260         NULL
A1          L1           2019012        2018012           280         NULL
A1          L1           2020001        2019001           300         NULL
A1          L1           2020002        2019002           320         NULL
A1          L1           2020003        2019003           340         NULL
```

Comment: Not reproducible - works as stated [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e8d3c7eb7ef30432101a9481afd4b0b)

Comment: Thanks Dale. It's weird that I am getting this error. I  actually have a larger dataset and this is the crux of the issue. Will check for other columns.

Comment: Thats why you need to test your [mre] before posting.

Comment: @SDR . . . The locations/accounts would seem to not line up.

Comment: Been banging my head for the solution. Finally found it. This is because some of the values in my other columns for the join condition are NULL. That is resulting in NULL results. Got that sorted. Thank you. I've used a COALESCE in the join conditions and that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A1.*, A2.Net_Amount AS LY_Net_Amount
FROM Account AS A1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account AS A2
    ON  COALESCE(A1.Account_ID,'') = COALESCE(A2.Account_ID,'')
    AND COALESCE(A1.Location_ID,'') = COALESCE(A2.Location_ID,'')
    AND A1.LY_Fiscal_Period = A2.Fiscal_Period
```

Some of my other columns have NULL in them and hence the issue. The COALESCE added now in the join condition solves the issue.

Comment: That doesn't match your sample data since you show string account ids, but use 0 in your coalesce. In fact it doesn't match your sample data at all, because you don't show any nulls. And does a null really match a null?

Comment: I've updated the statement now Dale and you are right it doesnt match with the sample data I have provided. I missed out on the other columns where there is NULL data in them and I am using  them in the JOIN condition. USing COALESCE in the join condition for Strings to be replaced with '' and numbers to replaced by 0 sorts my problem since by default input number can never be 0

Answer (score -1):

Your join is on last year fiscal period to this year fiscal period

```
AND A1.LY_Fiscal_Period = A2.Fiscal_Period
```

Which will never match.

Thats why you are getting null. Try the following:

```
AND A1.LY_Fiscal_Period = A2.LY_Fiscal_Period
```

Comment: Of course it matches? Thats the entire intention of the OP, is to match last year to this year. See my fiddle above.